# How many rows were copied from table

Tags: postgresql, psql, copy

I want to write a script to backup a table using `COPY`.

```
psql "connection parameters" -c "COPY (SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE insertion_date > 'date') TO STDOUT WITH CSV HEADER;" | bzip2 -c > backup.csv.bz2
```

Now I want to log how many lines are copied to zip file? I want to calculate it while copying, not with another command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update:** Since Postgres 9.3 plpgsql can access the number of rows processed by `COPY` directly:

- [Get the count of rows from a COPY command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16610449/get-the-count-of-rows-from-a-copy-command)

---

I recently ran into the same problem. I tried with a plpgsql function, but `ROW_COUNT` is not set by `COPY` - in Postgres 9.2 or older.

You *could* just run two queries. First `count()` and then `COPY`. With simple queries that's probably the way to go. But with huge / complex queries this is a pain and can double the execution time.

I came up with a solution that uses a temporary table and counts the rows before executing `COPY`.

I adapted what I have for you so you can `COPY TO STDOUT` and pipe to `bzip2`, which is not possible from within a plpgsql function:

#### 1. Create a function that takes an SQL string and creates a temporary table with it:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_copy_prep(_query text)
  RETURNS void AS
$func$
DECLARE
   ct integer;
BEGIN
   -- If you deal with huge results, set more RAM for temp tables locally:
   -- SET temp_buffers = 512MB';  -- example value

   EXECUTE 'CREATE TEMP TABLE cp_tmp ON COMMIT DROP AS (' || _query || ')';

   GET DIAGNOSTICS ct = ROW_COUNT;
   RAISE LOG 'My text here. rows: %', ct;

END
$func$  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
ALTER FUNCTION f_copy_prep(text) SET search_path=public,pg_temp;
REVOKE ALL ON FUNCTION f_copy_prep(text) FROM public;
GRANT EXECUTE ON FUNCTION f_copy_prep(text) TO ???;
```

- Function executes dynamic SQL, so you can use it for *any* query.
- This is inherently **unsafe**, so run it with the minimum rights necessary, revoke all rights from public and grant `EXECUTE` exclusively to a trusted user. [Follow the instructions in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-createfunction.html#SQL-CREATEFUNCTION-SECURITY)!
- Create temporary table with `ON COMMIT DROP`, so it gets dropped automatically at the end of the transaction.
- Get the row count with [`GET DIAGNOSTICS`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-DIAGNOSTICS) - `ROW_COUNT` is set by the `SELECT` statement in `EXECUTE`. Write it to the log - your requirement. No need for a separate `count(*)`.

#### 2. Call from shell-script to pipe output through bzip2

```
psql "connection parameters" \
-c "SELECT f_copy_prep('SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE insertion_date > ''date'''); \
    COPY cp_tmp TO STDOUT WITH CSV HEADER;" \
| bzip2 -c > backup.csv.bz2
```

- Put two SQL commands into your `-c` argument or put complex queries in a file and use the `-f` parameter. All is executed in one transaction. Only the output of the last command is returned - fits our need. Careful with the syntax - multiple layers of interpretation (first shell, then Postgres).
- First command is the above function with your query-string as parameter. Second is the `COPY TO STDOUT`.

I tested this with `PostgreSQL 9.1` on Linux and it worked for me: data in the file, message with row-count in the log.